# How can I block low voltage?

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, digital-logic, low-power, low-voltage

I have added a picture about my circuit. Please look at the picture. How can I safely provide the logic in the image? What kind of circuit should be in low voltage control block?
I have to cut off Vo1 at low voltage (case of Vi<7 V).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That block is called *undervoltage protection*, and it takes many forms, and they depend on your voltages, speed and current requirements for it. Also, many voltage regulators directly integrate that functionality.

Other than that, I think your notation has a bug, so I'm not 100% sure what to make of it.

Also note that your Vo being 0V is rarely what you really want. Usually you just want to "disconnect" the positive rail and leave a ground connection, but that, again, depends on what you're in for.

Generally, modern switch-mode power supplies do *all your flow chart* from grid to Vo2 for you, at high reliability, safely, more efficient, and for a price that your transformer-based solution can't compete with, so I'd honestly not bother, and just buy a sufficiently sized off-the-shelf supply.

Comment: I have fixed picture.Actually,Vi=Vi1.I have removed Vi1.So,I am using 7805 regulator.And 7805 has not low voltage protection.If a voltage of 7 volts or more comes to the low voltage control block, it should be transmitted to the regulator as it is(There may be some voltage lost. Not a problem. 0.5 volts for example.). 
But if the voltage is lower than 7 volts at this block, approximately 0 volts should be seen at the output of the block.

Comment: My total current requirement is no more than 20 milliamps.

Comment: yeah then definitely, don't use your expensive setup there, but just a 5V plug-in supply, like for old cellphones or other small gadgets. https://www.ebay.de/itm/393313699935?hash=item5b9352c85f:g:fdUAAOSwFUZgm7Al probably even has lower ripple than your 7805.

Comment: No,This is not solution for me.I don't want it for personal use.I am making a circuit.I need to control as electronic.Such as,something done using tlv431

Comment: What? That makes no sense. The thing you're building is *worse* than a commercially available adapter. I know enough expensive devices that simply buy such "wall wart" power supplies: choose the right tools for your job. And "such, something done using TLV431": Oh dear. That's not something useful in your situation.